# Using reflection to cast a object

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm a little new to reflection so forgive me if this is a more basic question I'm writing a program in c# and am trying to write a generic Empty or null checker method
so far the code reads as

```
 public static class EmptyNull
    {
       public static bool EmptyNullChecker(Object o)
       {
           try
           {
               var ob = (object[]) o;
               if (ob == null || !ob.Any())
                   return true;
           }
           catch (Exception e)// i could use genercs to figure out if this a array but                  //figured i just catch the exception
           {Console.WriteLine(e);}
           try
           {
               if (o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]"))
               //the following line is where the code goes haywire
              var ob = (List<o.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].ReflectedType>)o;
               if (ob == null || !ob.Any())
                   return true;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           { Console.WriteLine(e); }
           return o == null || o.ToString().Equals("");//the only thing that can return "" after a toString() is a string that ="", if its null will return objects placeMarker
       }
    }
```

now obviously the for a list i need a way to figure out what type of generic list it is so i want to use reflection to figure it out and then cast it with that reflection is this possible

Thank You

Comment: Whatever else you do, move the test for null to top. You have all sorts of null dereferencing right now.

Comment: Where are these objects coming from that you've lost all type information?

Comment: anywhere i dont really care its just a generic method that i can use all over my program to quickly figure out if this object that im dealing with is empty or null -- instead of writing out a check for every specific item i am using

Answer (score 9):

If all you want is a single method that returns true if an object is null or if the object is an empty enumerable, I wouldn't use reflection for that. How about a couple of extension methods? I think it would be cleaner:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        return obj == null || !obj.Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: cant because ill be using this for list of standard objects alsosuch as list<string>

Comment: @AlexKrups: sorry, not sure if I follow what the problem is. `List<string>` objects can be passed in with this.

Comment: List<string> implements IEnumerable<T>, so it will work with this code, as will any other class that implements the interface. In this case, you really need to let the type system work for you, instead of trying to cover all your bases with reflection. Don't reinvent the square wheel.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 4, you can take [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)'s new support for covariance into account, and write this as:

```
public static bool EmptyNullChecker(Object o)
{
    IEnumerable<object> asCollection = o as IEnumerable<object>;
    return o != null && asCollection != null && !asCollection.Any(); 
}
```

I would, however, suggest a better name such as one inspired by [string.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx)